# OAuth and OWIN Authentication - Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, openid-connect, dotnetopenauth

I have been asked to create a 'Authentication/Authorization' Middle man or broker as an http,MVC web application, so that this can be used to multiple applications on our organization for authentication/Authorization purposes. Means, users will signup, Login on this broker application and once confirmed Authenticated, authorized user, he will get redirected to client applications accordingly. This is the use case.

I am choosing OAuth and OWIN to develop this broker in an MVC applicaiton, which means OAuth(Authorization) will issue access token + refresh token, once user is successfully authenticated. I use normal, simple, minimal authentication logic inside the Oauth Authorization Server's Login Controller as below :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            var isPersistent = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("isPersistent"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get("submit.Signin")))
            {
             var user = Constants.Users.UserCollection.Where(u => u.Email.ToLower() == Request.Form["username"].ToLower().Trim() && u.Password == Request.Form["password"].Trim());

                if (user.Count() > 0)
                {
                    authentication.SignIn(
                        new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent },
                        new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                        { new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, Request.Form["username"]),
                         new Claim("DisplayName", user.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName) } , "Application"));                          


                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

This is the MSFT sample application I am following to develop this conceptual application. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server.

My question here is : I read in many articles like, its not good  to use Oauth authentication, else use OPENID Connect handling authentication. To be frank, I am not used with OPENID Connect and I am not sure about the necessity of creating a OPENID Provider for my organization, Since this service will be used only by customers of our organization - less than 200,000 users. We hardly need a user signup and login, this account need to be used among different web applications of our organization. Please help me here with your inputs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about the benefits of OpenID Connect (OIDC) over OAuth 2.0.

OIDC builds upon OAuth 2.0 so you can use all of it's features. In a practical context, the question you should ask yourself is: Do other applications (clients, APIs), which use your "broker" (authorization server/security token service/OpenID provider) need to know something about the user, who just logged in? Do they need the ID, it's roles, username etc..? If the answer is no and you just need a signed token you are probably better of with OAuth.

If you start to include user claims (=attributes) in your access token you should at least have a look at OIDC. Also note, that even if you include claims in your access token, these are meant for the resource server (=API) and are normaly inaccessable for the client (unless you extract them and expose them on the API side - this is basically what the OIDC `userinfo` endpoint does).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am exposing user attributes(displayname, email etc) through resource server api . So once user have access token, he will be able to fetch user attributes through resource server API endpoints which is marked as [Authorize] . The above MSFT sample also tells that. Will that be an issue ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that - it might get tedious/inconsistent if you have serveral resource servers (aka APIs)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for replying